# How to insert data to the commit using the console? VueX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to do it this way.

However, the return is not defined.

The status of the object is visible, I just can't change it.

```
App.$store.commit("setForm", {entrada:'245435'})
```

> undefined

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-feistel-26r4v?file=/src/store.js

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is not watching for updates from the store. It is only receiving `this.$store.state.form` on creation.

After running `App.$store.commit("setForm", {entrada:'245435'})` in the console, if you run `App.$store.state.form` you will see that `entrada: "245435"` has changed on the store.

If you want the form to watch for changes from the store, make it a computed like so:

```
  computed: {
    form() {
      return this.$store.state.form;
    }
```